# "collisionImpulse" of contact delegate method is always zero for strong collisions (SceneKit)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a SceneKit project that consists of a "floor" surrounded by "walls". A single sphere rolls around on the floor and collides with the walls depending on device orientation (I'm using `CoreMotion`).

This question pertains to `contact.collisionImpulse` located in the following `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` method:

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {

}
```

Please assume that I've correctly set up the `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` strategy.

**The goal, here, is to have a perfectly round/smooth sphere that reliably sends a correctly configured `SCNPhysicsContact` object to the `physicsWorld` method when there's a collision. A sphere that is not round/smooth enough does not roll predictably.**

After much trial and error, I've determined that there are two scenarios at play:

1. The sphere's physics body is perfectly round/smooth, but `collisionImpulse` is zero when the collision is relatively strong. Weaker collisions, however, result in non-zero values. Both of the following physics bodies result in this behavior:

```
let ballNode: SCNNode? = ballScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Sphere", recursively: true)!

ballNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
```

```
let ballNode: SCNNode? = ballScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Sphere", recursively: true)!
let ballGeo = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)

ballNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: ballGeo))
```

2. The sphere's physics body has small, flat sides all over it, but `collisionImpulse` is non-zero regardless of collision strength. Both of the following physics bodies result in this behavior:

```
let ballNode: SCNNode? = ballScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Sphere", recursively: true)!

ballNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: ballNode!.geometry!))
```

```
let ballNode: SCNNode? = ballScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Sphere", recursively: true)!

ballNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: ballNode!) )
```

Other things I've tried:

1. Using the `didUpdate` and `didEnd` versions of the `physicsWorld` method instead of the `didBegin` version -- to no avail.
2. I tried accomplishing the same thing using the method's `contact.pentrationDistance` -- to no avail.

I'm testing this on a real device.

**Question: What's going on, here, and how can I achieve a smooth sphere that will correctly trigger contact information?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After consulting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70819959/3919052), I decided to play around with `SCNPhysicsShape.Option.collisionMargin`.

I don't know why, but doing two things seems to have solved the problem:

1. Configuring the sphere's physics body by passing in a `collisionMargin` value of 1.0, like this:

```
ballNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(
    type: .dynamic,
    shape: SCNPhysicsShape(
       geometry: ballGeo,
       options: [
          .collisionMargin: 1.0,
          .type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.convexHull
       ]
    )
)
```

2. Decreasing the radius of the sphere's underlying geometry, like this:

```
let ballGeo = SCNSphere(radius: 0.15)
```

The sphere is now smooth enough to roll around nicely, and `collisionImpulse` is non-zero for all collisions.